# Incorrect content in string array of arrays

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to solve [Advent of Code 2020](https://adventofcode.com/2020) [Day 11 part 1](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/11) but run into a blocker issue. The puzzle is a game of life variant.

It looks like the output of the program depends on the size of the input data structure (array of arrays) even when the extra input data doesn't affect to the computations.

The correctness of the program is defined by evaluating the status of the first line after two iterations.

Here is the output of the correct execution (CORRECT):

```
CORRECT =======================
(xMax = 9)(yMax = 4)
iteration 1 -------------------
update: (5,0): count: 0: L -> #
update: (6,0): count: 0: L -> #
update: (7,0): count: 0: . -> .
update: (8,0): count: 0: L -> #
update: (9,0): count: 0: L -> #
iteration 2 -------------------
update: (5,0): count: 4: # -> L
update: (6,0): count: 3: # -> #
update: (7,0): count: 0: . -> .
update: (8,0): count: 3: # -> #
update: (9,0): count: 3: # -> #
iteration 3 -------------------
x: ["#",".","L","L",".","L","#",".","#","#"]
```

There you can see that after the second iteration the value of the first line is:

```
["#",".","L","L",".","L","#",".","#","#"]
```

that is correct.

When that is compared to the incorrect execution (INCORRECT) we notice that all those update (`update:`) steps are the same but the value of the first line is different and incorrect:

```
INCORRECT =====================
(xMax = 9)(yMax = 5)
iteration 1 -------------------
update: (5,0): count: 0: L -> #
update: (6,0): count: 0: L -> #
update: (7,0): count: 0: . -> .
update: (8,0): count: 0: L -> #
update: (9,0): count: 0: L -> #
iteration 2 -------------------
update: (5,0): count: 4: # -> L
update: (6,0): count: 3: # -> #
update: (7,0): count: 0: . -> .
update: (8,0): count: 3: # -> #
update: (9,0): count: 3: # -> #
iteration 3 -------------------
x: ["#",".","L","L",".","L","L",".","L","L"]
```

The value of the first line depends only on the first and second lines so I would expect the program output to be identical with 5 and 6 input lines.

Please find the bug !

I'm using Swan Lake Preview 5:

```
$ ballerina version
Ballerina Swan Lake Preview 5
Language specification v2020-09-22
Update Tool 0.8.10
```

The program:

```
import ballerina/io;

string & readonly EMPTY_SEAT = "L";
string & readonly OCCUPIED_SEAT = "#";

int xMax = 0;
int yMax = 0;

function x(string[][] seatMap) {

    xMax = seatMap[0].length() - 1;
    yMax = seatMap.length() - 1;

    string[][] currentSeatMap = seatMap.clone();
    string[][] nextSeatMap = seatMap.clone();

    io:println(string`(xMax = ${xMax})(yMax = ${yMax})`);

    foreach var index in 1 ... 3 {
        io:println(string`iteration ${index} -------------------`);

        if index == 3 {
            io:println("x: ", currentSeatMap[0]);
            break;
        }

        // recalculate all seats    
        foreach var 'tuple1 in currentSeatMap.enumerate() {
            var [y, line] = 'tuple1;
            foreach var 'tuple2 in line.enumerate() {
                var [x, seat] = 'tuple2;
                update(currentSeatMap, nextSeatMap, x, y, seat);
            }
        }

        currentSeatMap = nextSeatMap.clone();
    }
}

function update(string[][] currentSeatMap, string[][] nextSeatMap, int x, int y, string seat) {
    int count = 0;
    match seat {
        EMPTY_SEAT => {
            count = countAdjacentSeats(currentSeatMap, x, y, OCCUPIED_SEAT);
            if  count == 0 {
                nextSeatMap[y][x] = OCCUPIED_SEAT;
            }
        }
        OCCUPIED_SEAT => {
            count = countAdjacentSeats(currentSeatMap, x, y, OCCUPIED_SEAT);
            if count >= 4 {
                nextSeatMap[y][x] = EMPTY_SEAT;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if y == 0 && x > 4 {
      io:println(string`update: (${x},${y}): count: ${count}: ${currentSeatMap[y][x]} -> ${nextSeatMap[y][x]}`);
    }
}

function countAdjacentSeats(string[][] currentSeatMap, int x, int y, string seatType) returns int {
    int count = 0;
    // up left
    if (x-1 >= 0) && (y-1 >= 0) {
        if currentSeatMap[y-1][x-1] == seatType {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    // up
    if (y-1 >= 0) {
        if currentSeatMap[y-1][x] == seatType {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    // up right
    if (x+1 <= xMax) && (y-1 >= 0) {
        if currentSeatMap[y-1][x+1] == seatType {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    // left
    if (x-1 >= 0) {
        if currentSeatMap[y][x-1] == seatType {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    // right
    if (x+1 <= xMax) {
        if currentSeatMap[y][x+1] == seatType {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    // down left
    if (x-1 >= 0) && (y+1 <= yMax) {
        if currentSeatMap[y+1][x-1] == seatType {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    // down 
    if (y+1 <= yMax) {
        if currentSeatMap[y+1][x] == seatType {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    // down right
    if (x+1 <= xMax) && (y+1 <= yMax) {
        if currentSeatMap[y+1][x+1] == seatType {
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

public function main() {
    // after second iteration the first subarray is
    // ["#",".","L","L",".","L","L",".","L","L"]
    // that is incorrect
    string[][] incorrect = [
        ["L",".","L","L",".","L","L",".","L","L"],
        ["L","L","L","L","L","L","L",".","L","L"],
        ["L",".","L",".","L",".",".","L",".","."],
        ["L","L","L","L",".","L","L",".","L","L"],
        ["L",".","L","L",".","L","L",".","L","L"],
        ["L",".","L","L","L","L","L",".","L","L"]
        // [".",".","L",".","L",".",".",".",".","."],
        // ["L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L"],
        // ["L",".","L","L","L","L","L","L",".","L"],
        // ["L",".","L","L","L","L","L",".","L","L"]
    ];

    // after second iteration the first subarray is
    // ["#",".","L","L",".","L","#",".","#","#"]
    // that is correct
    string[][] correct = [
        ["L",".","L","L",".","L","L",".","L","L"],
        ["L","L","L","L","L","L","L",".","L","L"],
        ["L",".","L",".","L",".",".","L",".","."],
        ["L","L","L","L",".","L","L",".","L","L"],
        ["L",".","L","L",".","L","L",".","L","L"]
    //     ["L",".","L","L","L","L","L",".","L","L"],
    //     [".",".","L",".","L",".",".",".",".","."],
    //     ["L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L"],
    //     ["L",".","L","L","L","L","L","L",".","L"],
    //     ["L",".","L","L","L","L","L",".","L","L"]
    ];

    io:println("INCORRECT =====================");
    x(incorrect);

    io:println("CORRECT =======================");
    x(correct);
}
```